# Custom fields in confirmation email Opencart 2.0

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have created custom fields for my registration/checkout form with Opencart 2.0. They show up on the admin section under each order, and I have successfully added them to the `order_invoice.tpl`, but I need to add them to the confirmation email that is sent to the customer. I think I have located the correct controller file: `catalog>controller>account>order.tpl` But I think the issue is that the code used to print it out in the `order_invoice.tpl` is referencing a folder or file in the admin side.

This is the code I am trying to execute in catalog>view>theme>yourtheme>template>mail>order.tpl

```
<?php foreach ($account_custom_fields as $custom_field) { ?>      
    <strong><?php echo $custom_field['name']; ?></strong>:
    <?php echo $custom_field['value']; ?><br />
<?php } ?>
```

This is the error I get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: account_custom_fields in
>   /home/raphaelseventworks.com/www/ncbaorders/catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/mail/order.tpl
>   on line 70Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/raphaelseventworks.com/www/ncbaorders/catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/mail/order.tpl
>   on line 70

Does anyone know how print out custom fields in the order confirmation email? Or what code I need to add to `catalog>controller>account>order.tpl` to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct you are trying to send additional values to confirmation email after checkout

you need to work on

```
catalog/model/checkout/order.php::addOrderHistory()
```

After order is placed, the order history is changed, here you can load your view file and pass custom values form controller according to your need.

Good Luck
[image]